# Attempting recursion in Python

Tags: python, csv, recursion

I am attempting to make this program function in a recursive manner. The program takes in a csv file, calls on columns and takes the distance between the begin and end points. Within lengths of 10 miles, random samples are taken from the begin point and up to the end point. If the sample is still less than the end point - 2, a new sample is taken then miles down the road from varOut. It is my goal to have this program do this recursively. But im new to recursion. At this point the only output im getting is None, so im wondering what exactly is causing this to happen.

```
import csv
import math
import random as r

def yielderOut(length):
    n = 0
    rounder = 3
    readerIn()
    for col in csv.DictReader(open('2015_FILES_COMBINED.CSV')):
        corridorRB = str(col['CORRIDOR_CODE_RB'])
        begMi = float(col['FRFPOST'])
        endMi = float(col['TRFPOST'])
        dir_ = str(col['DIR'])
        if abs(begMi - endMi) > length and dir_ == 'I':
            varOut = round(r.uniform((math.ceil(begMi) + 1), (math.floor(begMi) + (length))), rounder)
            if varOut < (endMi - 2):
                return yielderOut(varOut + length), n + 1
            else:
                return corridorRB, round(begMi, rounder), round(endMi, rounder), 'Increasing', varOut, n

yielderOut(10)
```

**data**

```
 CORRIDOR_CODE_RB        FRFPOST         TRFPOST         DIR
      C000001E             0           667.145996         I
      C000001E        667.145996            0             D
      C000003N             0              110.5           I
      C000003N           110.5              0             D
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Also, you could put all the `import` statements at the beginning of the file; it's neater that way.

Comment: Ok good advice. I edited the intro message again that gives more of a question to be answered.

Comment: The first `for` loop creates a bunch of `csv.DictReader`s but only saves the last one into `fileData`. What is `readerOut()`?

Comment: If your `for` loop completes without ever entering the `if abs(...` block, then nothing gets returned. If you're about to say, "that's fine, the code should never reach that point", consider adding a `raise Exception("never expected to reach this point!")` statement at the end of your function to verify this.

Comment: BTW, Python doesn't encourage recursion - it limits the number of recursive calls and it doesn't do tail-call optimization. So it's generally better to use a non-recursive algorithm, when practical. Of course, some problems are recursive by nature and it can be very awkward to formulate them non-recursively. Your problem may be like that, but it's not easy to tell from your question. :)

Comment: readerOut() is another function im calling that is yielding in the csv

Comment: That's fine if recursion is not a good idea. I have this program in a non recursive format that works great. I just thought it would be worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what your function does without any sample data...

But the reason you're getting `None` returned is that when the condition

```
abs(begMi - endMi) > length and dir_ == 'I'
```

is not true for any `col` then when the `for` loop is finished your function will return the default value of `None`.

Comment: CORRIDOR_CODE_RB FRFPOST TRFPOST DIR
C000001E                         0          667.145996   I
C000001E                 667.145996         0          D

Comment: There is some sample input above

Comment: @hollow_Victory: Could you please edit some sample input into your question itself? Preferably more than one line, unless one line is adequate to illustrate your algorithm.

Comment: Sure I can do that I think